# Branch office network

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-asa, firewall, hp

We going to open branch office.
In Head office we have 2 ASA firewalls (active-standby) and 2960 switches on each floor.

How can i connect branch office to the main office ?
I have 2901 Router and HP 1910-8 Switch. Can they work properly ?

Comment: Do your different sites use private addressing internally?

Comment: Yes, but i think to use same VLANs on both offices.

Comment: The VLAN numbers don't matter because you will have a layer-3 separation.

Comment: Should i use Site-To-Site VPN connection ?

Comment: What kind of connection do you have between offices?  What is the bandwidth?

Comment: ISP fiber connection 4mb/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.  The ASA's potentially have deeper packet inspection / security functionality than the 2901 router.  So, do you centralize the ISP/Internet access out of HQ, or have split tunneling so that the branch office uses a local Internet pipe and IOS-firewall (CBAC) on the 2901?  Figure that out... See FirePower add-on bundle for ASA's.

In terms of enabling connectivity between your IP endpoints (computers/printers/etc) in these 2 locations, that's called a VPN tunnel.  You'll be interested in a [Site-to-Site VPN tunnel between ASA and 2901](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/ipsec-negotiation-ike-protocols/119425-configure-ipsec-00.html).

Comment: Planes have changed. I still have Cisco ASA on HQ with a static public ip address but for branch office now i have Huawei ISR with a dynamic public address and it doesnt support VPN. Is there any solutions to connect both sides?

Comment: if the Huawei supports VPN tunnels, you can get it working even if one side has a dynamically assigned (routable) IP address.

Comment: Hello Ron,
But problem is the Huawei router doesnt support vpn. But is it possible to configure VPN on Cisco 2901 router and connect to the Huawei ? 

And

Comment: I spoke with ISP and they can provide me connection with satellite, but only with internal traffic. I mean our ISPs have peering. So even if dont have access to Internet (e.g google.com, facebook and etc.) i still have access to our internal website on ,tj domain. Is it possible to make VPN with this type of connection ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using private addressing internally at each site, you need to set up a tunnel between the sites over the public Internet, and it would be wise to encrypt the contents of the tunnel (VPN). When you have the tunnel in place, you can route traffic between the two sites in the tunnel.

You are using Cisco equipment, and Cisco maintains documentation on how to set up site-to-site tunnels, e.g. [*Site-to-Site and Extranet VPN Business Scenarios*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_modules/6342/vpn_cg/6342site3.html), but you can search for other documents, too.